# Function declared under Button action not working

Tags: swift, xcode

I am making an app and when you press a button I need some functions to run. I have no errors yet when you press the button nothing happens

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBOutlet var Background: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var RedOverlay: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Text: UILabel!



    var timer = Timer()
    var seconds = 3
    var timerRunning = false


    @IBAction func screenPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        func runTimer() {
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: (#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            timerRunning = true
            }
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        seconds -= 1
        Text.text = String(seconds)
        if seconds < 2 {
            timer.invalidate()
            UILabel.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.Text.alpha = 0
            })
            backgroundChange()
        }
    }

    func backgroundChange() {
        let wait = Int.random(in: 1 ... 10)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(wait), execute: {
            self.Text.alpha = 1
            self.Text.text = "Go"
            self.RedOverlay.alpha = 1
        })
    }
}
```

I use storyboards so the function is connected to the button via an outlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining your function inside the IBAction.

Move your

```
func Runtimer() { ... }
```

outside of it and call it from inside:

```
@IBAction func screenPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    runTimer()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrapped your Timer call inside of a function (`runTimer()`), but you never actually execute the function.  I would just remove the function wrapper.

```
    @IBAction func screenPressed(_ sender: Any) {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: (#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            timerRunning = true
    }
```